# what "non-continuous nature of scores" means

Tags: scales, validation

1) Can someone explain me the idea of this sentence:

"It is noted that nonparametric tests were employed because of the non-continuous nature of the scale scores" (this is related to scale validity that is tested after survey)

2) What kind of tests could be used?

Answer (score 2):

1) Non-continuous means discrete. The scale scores could e.g. have been 0 to 5 with **discrete** steps of 1. If any value could have been filled in e.g. 1.4, 4.332 etc. than the scale is said to be continuous.

2) There is a wide variety of non-parametric tests, depending on what you want to investigate. Check for example [here](http://www.stats.gla.ac.uk/steps/glossary/nonparametric.html) for some possible tests.